# Selenium how to find an image by src that contain a string

Tags: python, selenium

I don't find an image on page with selenium. My script is in python.

```
    try:
        is_captcha = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src*='validation']")
        if is_captcha:
            print("CAPTCHA FOUND!")
    except:
        try:
            is_captcha = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[src*='validation']")
            if is_captcha:
                print("CAPTCHA FOUND!")
        except:
            print ("No catpcha form for {}".format(link_hyip))
```

The HTML code where my image is :

```
<td class="menutxt"><img src="?a=show_validation_image&amp;PHPSESSID=u020264onvkgu0fsl9b94lk1v1&amp;rand=1901750303"></td>
```

I got this error :

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[src*='validation']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

thank for you help !

Comment: Why are you looking for a css-selector? I think you should use xpath and search the image source... Something like `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, 'validation')]")`.

Comment: How about XPATH? `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//img[contains(@src, 'a=show_validation')]")`.

Comment: @nostradamus i got this error with the xpath :( no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src, 'validation')]"}

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Comment: whats the step to replicate this?

Comment: I'm trying to get the URL of the captcha on this page ( src of img balise ) : https://www.lanysoft.biz/?a=support
It's just on the top of the "send" button

Comment: check if the link is in frame.

Comment: @supputuri i don't think, i don't see any "frame" balise in the HTML

Comment: @ValentinGarreau : I am able to find the element.

Comment: @ValentinGarreau don't see any error on your code.

Comment: @KunduK so strange ... my code is passing into the except print 
`print ("No catpcha form for {}".format(link_hyip))`

Comment: Your locator looks fine... you just need to add a wait and then get rid of the try-catch and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WebdriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located` and the below xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.lanysoft.biz/?a=support')
try:
  is_captcha =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//form[@name='loginform']//img[contains(@src,'show_validation')]"))) 
  if is_captcha:
    print("CAPTCHA FOUND!")
except:
    print('recapcha not found')
```

Comment: Ok that's working well if i copy past in new file. I think i have probem in my file or environnement. I'll check and use this code thank you